# Custom error redirects not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config, http-status-codes

I'm trying to ensure that no non-standard error messages are sent to a user for security reasons. Generally I have standard error messages setup and it works perfectly fine. I use these tags in the web.config:

```
<httpErrors  errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="411" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="/ErrorPages/UnAuthorized.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="501" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="400" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="411" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="400" path="/Account/Login.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

The problem I am having is it has been pointed out that some 403,400,501 error messages still don't get redirected.

The urls that cause this problem are:

```
www.example.com/con/ - asp.net error

wwww.example.com/..%5CStorage%5CDocuments%5C8849145d-174a-41ab-9676-0ae19d6ab741    - 403 error
```

and 411 errors from invalid content length.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using VisualStudio Development Server or IIS7 Express?
If you are using it then you should try with:

```xml
<customErrors mode="On" >
  <error statusCode="503" redirect="/Views/Shared/Error.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

If not, try this:

```xml
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="Redirect" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="501"/>
  <error statusCode="501" responseMode="Redirect" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx"/>          
 </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Thanks I am using IIS 7.5 on a windows server. Your response has fixed all but one of the problems I am still getting "HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden." When entering wwww.site.com/..%5CStorage%5CDocuments%5C8849145d-174a-41ab-9676-0ae19d6ab741 any suggestions on how to redirect it to my custom error page?

Comment: ?And you change statusCode="403" setting in web.config to: <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="Redirect" path="/ErrorPages/UnAuthorized.aspx"/>

Comment: Yep exactly as below :
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="Redirect" path="/ErrorPages/UnAuthorized.aspx"/>